# Why aren't my multiple CSS attribute selectors working?

Tags: css

I have two forms, one that contains a form field for entering a username and a second form on another page where a user enters an email address:

```
<!-- user.html -->
<form action="/account/login/" method="post">
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <input type="text" name="username" autofocus autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" placeholder="Username" class="form-control form-control-md" required id="id_username">
  </div>
  <p class="mt-4"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Login"></p>
</form>


<!-- email.html -->
<form action="." method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" maxlength="254" placeholder="Email" class="form-control form-control-md" required id="id_email">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Email" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

I'm trying to style both input controls using multiple attribute selectors like this but it's not working.  The styles aren't being applied.

```
// styles.scss
form input[type=text][type=email] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

But if I separate the types into two separate rules like this, the styles do get applied properly.

```
form input[type=text] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

form input[type=email] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

The [CSS documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) says this should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation this matches when `type=email` **AND** `type=text` which can't be true.

> Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute
> has exactly the value "Cleveland" **and** whose "goodbye" attribute has
> exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> `span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }`

You would need to include both versions;

```
form input[type=text],
form input[type=email] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma after input with the type of text.